# sharedPreferences change listener in fragment not firing

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have the following as my onCreateView for my fragment

```
public static final String sharedPreferences = "crmPrefFiles";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_fragment1, container, false);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefefrences, 0);
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

                populatePage(layout);
            }
        };
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
        return layout;
    }
```

In the activity that uses the fragments the preferences get edited values grabbed via webservice call. This is why I use an onchangeListener. The fragment is created before the preferences are edited.

```
final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("FRAG_" + pageNum, record.getString("group"));
editor.commit(); //commit the changes
```

It appears now that the problem has to do with the listener not detecting the change made in the activity that creates the fragment itself.

The activity that hosts the fragments gets the values for the sharedpreferences and sets them. This is then supposed to be caught in the fragment itself and then call another method. For some reason the listener isn't detecting those changes.

When I output the preference that gets edited in a toast message I get the incorrect value, when I go back and re-enter the activity it has the correct value, this tells me it's being updated after the fragment is created but for some reason the listener isn't firing.

Comment: can you add the code where you try to change SharedPreferences values?

Comment: @pablobu added. The preferences are updated in the activity that uses the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)):

> Caution: The preference manager does not currently store a strong
>   reference to the listener. You must store a strong reference to the
>   listener, or it will be susceptible to garbage collection. We
>   recommend you keep a reference to the listener in the instance data of
>   an object that will exist as long as you need the listener.

Storing the listener into a instance variable should fix your problem. Also ensure you are adding the listener before getting the data from your webservice call.

Comment: When I update the preferences directly after adding the listener it fires. When I output the preference value directly before adding the listener it grabs the old value. Would that explain this behavior?

Comment: It sounds as your variable is being removed due to the type of reference preference manager has with the listener. Keeping the listener into an instance variable of your fragment should fix it.